# iPhone 5 screen adapt

Tags: ios, xcode

I am using this code to adapt my storyboard depending on device (iphone 5 or less):

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    if(UIScreenOverscanCompensationScale==1136/640){
        //move to your iphone5 storyboard
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iphone5 storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }
    else{
        //move to your iphone4s storyboard
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    }}
```

The code doesn't work even if I just place:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iphone5 storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

...it still loads iphone normal.

I put it under:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
```

in app delegate. Is this right?? In the app settings I chose the original iphone storyboard

Comment: On the Targets Summary page the storyboard is probably set to MainStoryboard_iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it in this way:

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568.0){
        //move to your iphone5 storyboard
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iphone5 storyboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        UIViewController *vc =[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

        // Set root view controller and make windows visible
        self.window.rootViewController = vc;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }
    else{
        //move to your iphone4s storyboard
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        UIViewController *vc =[storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

        // Set root view controller and make windows visible
        self.window.rootViewController = vc;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that:

```
UIScreenOverscanCompensationScale==1136/640
```

will never be true.

Check what `UIScreenOverscanCompensationScale` is doing and return a BOOL.

Answer (score 0):

Is `MainStoryboard` still specified under target summary? I believe that this will be where the app looks first.

Comment: well, I have decided on a storyboard under summary=> main storyboard.  because I have to decide on a storyboard.